# Change "Select Options" label in button to "Buy Now!" in store page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to change "Select Options" label in button to "Buy Now!" on my store page.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'wpse_woo_custom_cart_button_text' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'wpse_woo_custom_cart_button_text' );
function wpse_woo_custom_cart_button_text() {

  global $product;

  $product_type = $product->get_type();

  // To modify on a single product page
  if( $product_type == 'variable-subscription' || $product_type == 'variable' ){
    if( is_single() )
        return __( 'Buy Now', 'my-textdomain' );
    else
        return __( 'Choose options', 'my-textdomain' );
  }
  // To modify on the shop page
  else{
    switch ( $product_type ) {
      case 'external':
        return __( 'Buy Now', 'my-textdomain' );
      break;
      case 'grouped':
        return __( 'View products', 'my-textdomain' );
      break;
      case 'simple':
        return __( 'Buy Now', 'my-textdomain' );
      break;
  // here's your use case
      case 'variable':
        return __( 'Select Value', 'my-textdomain' );
       break;
  // Not a default product type
      case 'booking':
        return __( 'Book Now', 'my-textdomain' );
      break;
      default:
        return __( 'Learn more', 'my-textdomain' );
    }
  }
}
```

you can put this into your functions.php file

Comment: You shouldn't override all the other WooCommerce product type button texts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more succinct answer for the Shop page only and the WooCommerce Bookings plugin button text.

```
    function es_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text( $btn_text, $product ) {
        if('booking' === $product->get_type()) {
            return 'Book Now';
        }
    
        return $btn_text;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'es_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );
```